# In my Cypress.io tests why do I need to treat a cy.task like it is asyncronous when its not

Tags: cypress

I have [Cypress.io](https://docs.cypress.io/) tests that use a simple [Cypress task](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/task) to log some table information to the terminal. For example I have a test like so:

```
it("Writes some console logs and checks a val", () => {
  cy.task("rowLog", { id: 1, name: "foo", type: "bar" });
  let one = 1;
  expect(one).to.equal(2);
});
```

And the task, "rowLog" like so:

```
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on("task", {
  rowLog(data) {
    // use node.js console.table to pretty print table data:
    console.table(data);
    return null;
  },
}
```

But the result of `rowLog` will not display in my terminal if I run Cypress headlessly via `Cypress run`. This is because the test will fail. If we switch the test so that it passes, then it will show.

However I just realized that if I treat `rowLog` like it's async like below. It *will* print the results to the terminal:

```
it("Writes some console logs and checks a val", () => {
  // add a .then to task:
  cy.task("rowLog", { id: 1, name: "foo", type: "bar" }).then(() => {
    let one = 1;
    expect(one).to.equal(2);
  });
});
```

This is not what I would expect from the docs. They say that:

> cy.task() yields the value returned or resolved by the task event in the pluginsFile.
> ([source](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/task#Yields))

And that a task can yield either a promise **or a value**.

I'm new to Cypress here-- is there something I'm missing or doing wrong? I'd like to be able to not have to chain my tasks with `.then` statements if it is just synchronous stuff like writing output to ensure everything is emitted to my terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look into the type definition of `cy.task` command, you will see that it returns a Chainable (that is a promise-like entity). So it behaves like any other cy command (ansynchrounously).
As for the `yield either a promise or a **value**` - this statement refers to the **handler** of the task, not the task itself. As for the other command, Cypress will wrap a returned value into a promise if it was not done by the handler.

Comment: Thanks, so if I want to get the result of my cy.task I must then wrap everything subsequent in a `.then` statement? What if I want to run this task several times. How do I avoid chaining a whole bunch of `.then` statements? Is there a better approach?

Comment: yep, to handle the result of `cy.task`, you have to use a synchronous block of code (`then`, `should`).
The same as with other cy commands, you can call `cy.task` several times and Cypress will execute the tasks late in the same order. So no callback chain is required if you just want to call the tasks without handling the results.

Comment: This is not an answer to the original question. OP did not necessarily want to get the results of cy.task, instead he is wondering why Cypress does not wait for the task to complete. As far as I know it should wait for it to finish. Eg. `cy.task('foo').then(() => { expect(one).to.equal(2); })` and `cy.task('foo'); cy.wrap(1).should('equal', 2)` should be equivalent, but according to OP and my investigation in a sporadic bug, they are not equivalent.

Comment: I was unable to find it in the docs, but I admit the Cypress does not execute queued commands if an assertion failed.
As for your example - can you show that they are not equivalent?